# How to add classpath dependencies in build.gradle project?

Tags: java, android, gradle

After the Gradle update, every new project has this type of format in **build.gradle** (project:"...")

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Now how can I add classpath dependencies here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are adding firebase to your Android App it needs to look something like below.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository

    }
    dependencies {

        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

    }
}



plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `dependencies` section/method as shown in [the gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html):

```
dependencies{
    implementation 'group.id:artifact-id:version' 
}
```

If a dependency should be available both at compile- and runtime, declare it as `implementation` (not available for dependents) or `api` (also available for dependents). See [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) for more details on the difference between `api` and `implementation`.

If it should be available at compile-time only, use `compileOnly`.

Similarly, you can use `runtimeOnly` for dependencies that should only be used at runtime.

If a dependency should be available only during tests, add `test` before it, e.g. `testImplementation`.

The [docs on the Java Library Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) provide more details on that.